# Set up offline Ubuntu Repository

Tags: localrepository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I'm in a bit of a pinch! I have bunch of Ubuntu hosts (10.04)on a network that NEVER sees the internet. I need to be able to install software on these hosts but obviously do not have access to an Ubuntu repository. I've spent some time searching online but cannot find a tut on how to create an offline Ubuntu repository. My question is two fold:

1). How do I set up an Ubuntu offline repository and point a host to it?

2). Is there an easy way to use a windows host to download an entire Ubuntu Repo. (I have a windows host with an internet connection).